# Calling a function in a parent directive from child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a child directive called `dropDownSortMenu`. An element within this child directive has a `ng-click` function. Upon execution of this function, I want to call a function of the parent directive `customTable`.

The plnkr is located here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7b2mce9jsAXmJpfKjgdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were already very close to using the correct approach. You already had a controller present, but there were two things missing:

1. The sort function needs to be set on the parent directive controller's context. (i.e. `this`)
2. Then you need to `require: '^customTable'`. (the `^` is used to denote we are looking for a controller on a parent directive).

Now in `dropDownSortMenu`'s link function, you have access to the parent controller's context and can do anything you please.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/jDWVjBk1fmB5VSURrho8?p=preview)

Comment: oh gosh, yours is much better :)

Answer (score 0):

*Use the scope's event dispatchers*; [`$emit(name, args)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24emit) is used to send an event up to parent scopes, and [`$broadcast(name, args)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24broadcast) will sink events downwards through the hierarchy.
To catch thrown events use [`$on(name, listener)`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#methods_%24on) listeners.

You could just as well refer to `$scope.$parent` to travel up the chain (or `$scope.$parent.$parent` etc.), but this is **not recommended** - you will have to look up the scope hierarchy `n` levels up, rendering that code rigid (what if you change the scope nesting level, e.g. by adding an `ng-repeat` somewhere?).

---

You can also utilize *transclusion* in the directive (when appropriate) - which will allow your model to reside outside the directive's isolated scope, thus allowing natural access to any controller in the hierarchy above (provided that no isolated scope is in the way).
See [`$compile` service docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) for an explanation on the directives' `tranclude` property.